# Composition vs Prefix @

Tags: function-construction

Whats the difference between Composition @* and prefix @?

`Composition[f,g,h][x]
f@g@h[x]`

Functionally they both seem to give the same result.

Comment: Compare `f@*g /@ {x, y}` with `f@g /@ {x, y}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f, g]
h = f@g
h[x]      (* f[g][x] *)
h = f@*g
h[x]      (* f[g[x]] *)
```